# Pull Data Directly from FRED Website to Create Data Frame in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I am trying to pull data directly from the FRED website on GDP for each US state and Washington DC. I have provided an example for loop, an example of pulling an individual state's data, a vector of US state abbreviations, an empty dataframe to fill, and my for loop that currently is producing an "undefined columns selected" error.

```
# This is an example for loop for the thing I'm trying to do:

for (i in 1:10) {
location <- paste0('http://example.com/series', i, '.txt')
data[,i] <- read.table(location, sep=',')[,1]
}

# This is an example of pulling a single (small) database directly from the internet. The bracketed numbers at the end
# are 'indexing' rows and columns [row,column] to include and/or exclude:

NY <- read.csv('https://fred.stlouisfed.org/data/NYRGSP.txt', sep = '',header=F)[-1:-10,1:2]

# This creates a vector of state abbreviations to call:

states <- c('AL', 'AK', 'AZ', 'AR', 'CA', 'CO', 'CT', 'DE', 'FL', 'GA', 'HI', 'ID', 'IL', 'IN', 'IA', 'KS', 'KY', 'LA', 'ME', 'MD', 'MA', 'MI', 'MN', 'MS', 'MO', 'MT', 'NE', 'NV', 'NH', 'NJ', 'NM', 'NY', 'NC', 'ND', 'OH', 'OK', 'OR', 'PA', 'RI', 'SC', 'SD', 'TN', 'TX', 'UT', 'VT', 'VA', 'WA', 'WV', 'WI', 'WY', 'DC')

# This creates an empty dataframe:

fred <- data.frame()

# This is what I have so far, following the examples given above. I don't know why this produces the error "undefined columns
# selected"

for (i in 1:length(states)){
  location <- paste0('https://fred.stlouisfed.org/data/', states[i], 'RGSP.txt')
  fred[,i] <- read.table(location, sep = ',', header = F)[-1:-10,1:2]
}
```

credit to user apax for helping me initially get this far!

Comment: Please be aware that R does not recognize (tolerate) "fancy quotes", the single- and double-quotes that are curved/angled. This renders your code unusable without manually correcting all of them. If `‘.txt’` (<-- this literal) doesn't error for you, then I'm curious about your OS and system ... but please [edit] your question to replace all such fancy quotes with "simple" quotes. Thanks!

Comment: Ah sorry, editing now!

Comment: Can you share some links which are valid? I tried https://fred.stlouisfed.org/data/AL/RGSP.txt but that gives 404 error.

Comment: Hi Ronak, sure. Here you go: https://fred.stlouisfed.org/data/NYRGSP.txt

Comment: The iteration is over the state code (NY, AK, MO, etc.) portion of the URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an in-built constant in R for state name (`state.name`) and abbreviations (`state.abb`) which we can use to construct the url. In `read.table` use `skip = 10` to skip first 10 rows and keep `header = TRUE` since those files have header.

```
result <- lapply(paste0('https://fred.stlouisfed.org/data/',state.abb,'RGSP.txt'), 
                 function(x) read.table(x, header = TRUE, skip  = 10))
```

`result` above is a list of dataframes where each element is dataframe for each state. If you want to combine the results into one dataframe you can use `do.call` + `rbind`.

```
result <- do.call(rbind, result)
```

Comment: This is amazing Ronak, thank you! Doesn't grab DC but I can just pull that individually.